# google app script not rendering my translated message

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

```
function enes() {   
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()   
var text = doc.getSelection()   
var sourceLanguage = 'en'   
var targetLanguage = 'es'   
var replacement = LanguageApp.translate(text, sourceLanguage, 
targetLanguage)   
console.log(text + '=' + replacement)
}
```

This should log the selected text in console with the translation to Spanish but isn't for some reason. Please Help!

Comment: Hi Luke, Welcome to Stack Overflow, when posting a question you should include not only a code snippet but details regarding what you are looking for.

Comment: What does it print? Is `text` the correct selected text? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @goldenratio there aren't any errors in console and the text is the selected text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that the first argument of LanguageApp.translate() requires a string type and Document.getSelection() returns a Range Object. To get the text string out of the Range you can use the following code:

```js
function enes() {   
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()   
var text = doc.getSelection()
.getRangeElements()[0]
.getElement()
.asText()
.getText();
var sourceLanguage = 'en'   
var targetLanguage = 'es'   
var replacement = LanguageApp.translate(text, sourceLanguage, 
targetLanguage)   
Logger.log(text + '=' + replacement)
}
```

Note: I replaced console.log() with the native Logger.log() for testing convenience.

Additionally note: This will only return the first RangeElement. If you have more you can loop through them with something like:

```js
function enes() {   
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()   
var text = doc.getSelection()
.getRangeElements().getRangeElements().reduce(function(acc,rangeElement){
    return acc+rangeElement
    .getElement()
    .asText()
    .getText();
},"");
var sourceLanguage = 'en'   
var targetLanguage = 'es'   
var replacement = LanguageApp.translate(text, sourceLanguage, 
targetLanguage)   
Logger.log(text + '=' + replacement)
}
```

Comment: Why do you put the [0] after .getRangeElements()

Comment: Because .getRangeElements() returns an array and to keep things simple in the first script, I use the index operator [0] to access the first RangeElement in the array.   The second more complex script allows you to get the text from multiple RangeElements.